# Problems Compiling PySide on MacOSX

Tags: macos, pyside

I'm trying to compile PySide on a Mac (to use it with a software that has its own Python interpreter, that's why I can't use the binaries installers), and I have some issues I don't know how to solve...

I am using mac 10.8, and all dependencies (Cmake, XCode...) are up-to-date.

I don't know what's wrong, and I am now out of ideas.

here is the last part of what the compiler tells me:

```
Linking CXX executable testcontainer
[ 39%] Built target testcontainer
[ 39%] Generating testctorinformation.moc
Scanning dependencies of target testctorinformation
[ 39%] Building CXX object ApiExtractor/tests/CMakeFiles/testctorinformation.dir/testctorinformation.cpp.o
1 warning generated.
Linking CXX executable testcodeinjection
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "QCoreApplication::QCoreApplication(int&, char**, int)", referenced from:
      TestCodeInjections::testReadFileUtf8() in testcodeinjection.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [ApiExtractor/tests/testcodeinjection] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ApiExtractor/tests/CMakeFiles/testcodeinjection.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from /Users/jle_guen/Desktop/C4D MAC/BuildScripts-master/shiboken/ApiExtractor/tests/testconversionruletag.cpp:26:
In file included from /Users/jle_guen/Desktop/C4D MAC/BuildScripts-master/shiboken/ApiExtractor/tests/testutil.h:27:
In file included from /Users/jle_guen/Desktop/C4D MAC/BuildScripts-master/shiboken/ApiExtractor/abstractmetabuilder.h:28:
/Users/jle_guen/Desktop/C4D MAC/BuildScripts-master/shiboken/ApiExtractor/abstractmetalang.h:1347:10: warning: 
      private field 'm_reserveIn file included from /Users/jle_guen/Desktop/C4D MAC/BuildScripts-master/shiboken/ApiExtractor/tests/testconversionoperator.cpp:26:
In file included from /Users/jle_guen/Desktop/C4D MAC/BuildScripts-master/shiboken/ApiExtractor/tests/testutil.h:27:
In file included from /Users/jle_guen/Desktop/C4D MAC/BuildScripts-master/shiboken/ApiExtractor/abstractmetabuilder.h:28:
/Users/jle_guen/Desktop/C4D MAC/BuildScripts-master/shiboken/ApiExtractor/abstractmetalang.h:1347:10: warning: 
      private field 'm_reserved' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
d' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
    uint m_reserved : 31;
         ^
    uint m_reserved : 31;
         ^
1 warning generated.
Linking CXX executable testconversionruletag
[ 39%] Built target testconversionruletag
1 warning generated.
Linking CXX executable testconversionoperator
[ 39%] Built target testconversionoperator
In file included from /Users/jle_guen/Desktop/C4D MAC/BuildScripts-master/shiboken/ApiExtractor/tests/testctorinformation.cpp:25:
In file included from /Users/jle_guen/Desktop/C4D MAC/BuildScripts-master/shiboken/ApiExtractor/abstractmetabuilder.h:28:
/Users/jle_guen/Desktop/C4D MAC/BuildScripts-master/shiboken/ApiExtractor/abstractmetalang.h:1347:10: warning: 
      private field 'm_reserved' is not used [-Wunused-private-field]
    uint m_reserved : 31;
         ^
1 warning generated.
Linking CXX executable testctorinformation
[ 39%] Built target testctorinformation
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You mentioned that you are "out of ideas" - perhaps you can include what possibilities you've already eliminated.  That would help people answer your question.